# why I got this error msg when I execute this command

Tags: php, laravel

```
 $ php artisan infyom:scaffold User --fromTable --tableName=users
```

I get this error when I execute above command

> There are no commands defined in the "infyom" namespace.

Comment: Your laravel version?

Comment: I work with laravel 6

Comment: have you followed these steps https://labs.infyom.com/laravelgenerator/docs/6.0/installation 
Also try to run this command php artisan config:clear

Comment: no I did'nt I will try it and see  thank you very much

Comment: always the same msg :/

Comment: do you have a name space defined at the top of your migration file?

Comment: No ... how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by adding the last line in require into composer.json
"require": {
    "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "6.0.x-dev",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
    "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "6.0.x-dev",
     "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"
}
then run composer update and follow the next steps from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

run `php artisan config:cache'
update 'composer.json'

Check required class to be added!

Requires a lot of customization like:

Merge User.php with Models\User.php (and change all references)
Create a way to add a random password if empty and hash the provided one (editing repository)
Remove password from list
Is there a better way or Users are not intended to be managed?

Answer (score 0):

The following installed the versions I needed. I am using Lavarel 9.
My other lavarel installation never did worked. Lavarel 9 gave me no issues installing.

Found it on https://packagist.org/packages

composer require infyomlabs/laravel-generator
composer require infyomlabs/adminlte-templates
composer require doctrine/dbal
composer require laravelcollective/html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

{ "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "6.0.x-dev", "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0", "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "6.0.x-dev", "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3" }

This works perfectly fine